# How do I turn on theme_debug?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to use theme_debug to check which elements of a site use which .tpl files.

I have tried turning it on by using the drush command:

```
drush @mysite vset theme_debug 1
```

Though I do get the response `theme_debug was set to 1`, this does not seem to work.

Would anyone know if there is a way to get this working?

(Drush it's self seems to be working ok as I can use `drush @mysite cc all`)

Answer (score 21):

**Drush commands to control theme debugging:**

**Drupal 7**

- To turn it on: `drush variable-set theme_debug 1`
- To turn it off: `drush variable-set theme_debug 0`

**Drupal 8+**

- To turn it on: `drush state-set theme.debug 1`
- To turn it off: `drush state-set theme.debug 0`

Then clear your site cache and refresh the page in the browser.

Answer (score 10):

You process is right but this another option you can check.

In your Drupal 7 installation simply add this line to your settings.php:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

Clear your caches and refresh the page and you should see debug information in your mark-up which contains template suggestions.

Also go for [Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.

Comment: Using `drush` to turn debugging on/off will not require you to edit the `settings.php` file or install any additional modules.  It's easy to inadvertently cause other issues when editing `settings.php`, not to mention GIT permission issues if you aren't ignoring that file.  Also, adding a module to the site will cause performance issues, even if the module is disabled.

Comment: If theme_debug is explicitly disabled in settings.php, trying to enable it with drush will not work.

Answer (score -2):

> Step 1: Path :\sites\default\setting.php
>
> Step 2: Edit Setting.php:
>   remove `#` from
>
> `#$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;`
>
> Step 3: Save setting.php file
>
> Step 4: Inspect your website then you seen that theme information is show.